# executing jar from golanguage program in windows

Tags: java, windows, go, jar

```
'package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    //var java = "\\jrex64\\bin\\java.exe"
    var java ="jre/lib/java.exe"

    var path = []string{
        "jrex64\\lib\\rt.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jfxrt.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\resources.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunjce_provider.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\zipfs.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunmscapi.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunec.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\dnsns.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\access-bridge-64.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\security\\local_policy.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jce.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jfr.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jsse.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\charsets.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\",
    }

    var pathflag  string = "-Xbootclasspath:" + strings.Join(path, ";")
    cmd := exec.Command(java, "-verbose", pathflag, "-cp Ganesha_lib\\*", "-jar Ganesha.jar")
    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("an error occurred.\n")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

I want to call a jar file from go lang program in windows on window my java is installed in programfiles how do i set up the path for java variable and path variable in windows

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on which version you have of windows there is slightly different methods of setting your PATH and ENVIROMENT variables.

[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) you will find guides for most windows versions.